# get16bits macro in hash function

Tags: c, hash

I was looking at hash functions the other day and came across a website that had an example of one.  Most of the code was easy to grasp, however this macro function I can't really wrap my head around.

Could someone breakdown what's going on here?

```
#define get16bits(d) ((((uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8) +(uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]))
```

Comment: Well, the macro argument `d` is treated as a char array, and the first and zero'st chars of this are combined into a 16 bit int.

Comment: Yes, and this macro treats the memory that `d` points to as little-endian (possibly because it assumes the memory contains little-endian data, even if the system itself may be big-endian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it gets the lower 16 bit of the 32 bit integer d

lets break it down

```
#define get16bits(d) ((((uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8) +(uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]))
uint32_t a = 0x12345678;
uint16_t b = get16bits(&a); // b == 0x00005678
```

first we must pass the address of a to `get16bits()` or it will not work.

```
(((uint32_t)(const uint8_t *)(d))[1])) << 8
```

this first converts the 32 bit integer into an array of 8 bit integers and retrieves the 2 one.
It then shifts the value by 8 bit so it and adds the lower 8 bits to it

```
+ (uint32_t)(((const uint8_t *)(d))[0]))
```

In our example it will be

```
uint8_t tmp[4] = (uint8_t *)&a;
uint32_t result;
result = tmp[1] << 8; // 0x00005600
result += tmp[0]; //tmp[0] == 0x78
// result is now 0x00005678
```

Answer (score 1):

The macro is more or less equivalent to:

```
static uint32_t get16bits(SOMETYPE *d)
{
unsigned char temp[ sizeof *d];
uint32_t val;

memcpy(temp, d, sizeof *d);

val = (temp[0] << 8)
     + temp[1];
return val;
}
```

, but the macro argument has no type, and the function argument does.

Another way would be to actually cast:

```
static uint32_t get16bits(SOMETYPE *d)
{
unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char*) d;
uint32_t val;

val = (cp[0] << 8)
     + cp[1];
return val;
}
```

, which also shows the weakness: by indexing with 1, the code assumes that sizeof (*d) is at least 2.